# SC_MONITORPOWER messes up vsync

Tags: windows, winapi, opengl, nvidia, energy

I have a watchdog system service that monitors an OpenGL application for crashes, freezes, overheating CPU/GPU, scheduled on/off periods, etc. When the application is not running, due to this being a kiosk-style deployment, I call `BlockInput()` and power down the display with `PostMessage(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_MONITORPOWER, 2)`. When the monitored application is running again, the display is unsuspended with `PostMessage(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_MONITORPOWER, -1)`.

Well, it turns out that if the OpenGL application is launched with the display in low power mode, when the display comes on, vsync doesn't work in the application, regardless of graphics driver settings and calls to `wglSwapIntervalEXT()`. If the display is unsuspended before the application is launched (with some delay to give it time to actually power up), vsync works just fine. What's the fix here? I need the display blanked so random people in the mall don't see the desktop while the application is launching, but I also need vsync because we're seriously electrical power limited and it makes a huge difference (running top-end NVIDIA cards drawing a lot of juice).

The vsync signal comes from the graphics card, not the monitor, so this makes no sense. Even if the graphics card doesn't send out a vsync signal during the low power display mode, why wouldn't OpenGL latch on to the signal once it reappears when `SC_MONITORPOWER` is sent to unsuspend? I really need a work-around, as I doubt Microsoft and/or NVIDIA will fix this any time soon, if they're even aware of it (and I'd be going on a fool's errand trying to contact either -- I'm just some poor dev in the middle of nowhere).

Comment: You need VSYNC to limit power consumption? Have you considered artificially limiting your framerate? You could layer it on top of VSYNC, if you are drawing faster than say every 10.0 ms (100 FPS) then implement some form of blocking yourself. It will not interfere with VSYNC (I assume your monitor runs at a refresh <= 100 Hz), because when VSYNC ***is*** working correctly it will prevent your own framerate limiting code from ever kicking in.

Comment: Have you tried calling `wglSwapIntervalEXT` again every time the power-saving kicks in and out?

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman vsync solves both power and visual tearing issues.

Comment: Yes, I know that. My point was that if you want to limit power consumption during a period where there is no actual monitor attached (and thus no refresh rate to synchronize to), seek alternate means. In this case, limit the framerate yourself. If you limit it to some frequency ***higher*** than VSYNC, then you will not have to worry about your logic getting in the way of VSYNC when there is an actual working (powered up) monitor attached.

Comment: @BenVoigt I actually have adaptive vsync (I set it off if the previous frame took too long, and the reverse, with hysteresis achieved by different time thresholds in each direction of the transition), so I had assumed that it does get called. But I'll specifically test just in case transition back to vsync wasn't triggered by the particular test renderings.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman sorry, perhaps I wasn't quite clear. I mean I'm trying to limit power consumption _during_ active periods, when the content is being rendered. In some cases, the GPU is loaded heavily enough that the resulting framerate is lower than vsync, but that varies.

Comment: You were perfectly clear. According to your question, VSYNC is not working because you started your application before you had a powered up monitor. Whatever the reason VSYNC is not working, if you had manual frame limiting as a failsafe it would workaround the issue in the short-term.

Comment: I never feel comfortable relying on VSYNC for anything more than tearing prevention. It is so easy for an end-user to ***force*** it off in driver settings. Granted you generally do not have to worry about that if this is for a kiosk, the user should not have access to that sort of thing. But VSYNC is not something that you can really count on for a whole lot. If you have software requirements for limiting power consumption, you should have a fail-safe in place.